# Data type mismatch Error “UC_OBJECTS_NOT_CONVERTIBLE”

Tags: unicode, abap

Error in SAP-ABAP

Absolutely new in SAP-ABAP, running SAP benchmark but getting error while the clients executes.

Error “UC_OBJECTS_NOT_CONVERTIBLE”
[image]

The statement “MOVE src TO dest” needs same data-type for both src & des for proper execution.
however in this case ABAP code has this line 
Error in

“`SYSTEM-CALL SOLID POINTER MOVE OLE2_OBJ_POINTER TO OLE_HANDLE.`”

wherein the source and destination have different datatypes

Data type mismatch in source and destination objects

```
 OLE2_OBJ_POINTER TYPE OLE2_PCB
 DATA OLE_HANDLE TYPE OLE2_OBJECT.
```

[image]

Comment: Using `SYSTEM-CALL` in customer programs is not supported.

Comment: `SYSTEM-CALL SOLID POINTER` has just given me goosebumps. Which include does this subroutine come from?

Comment: there's no customization done to code. @Jagger program is SAPLOLEA and Include is LOLEAF01

Comment: @HimanshuSourav If this is an SAP include and it looks like the runtime exception is caused by the piece of code you posted, then you should raise an OSS incident at http://service.sap.com/support.